# Javascript/jQuery - remove/add class for multiple elements based on numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question seems like a repeat, but I've waded through many similar questions and have had no success.

I am working with a financial reporter and want to make negative balances red and positive balances green.

Here is my current jQuery. When I debug in the browser, the entire function gets skipped. Yet for some reason, my classes are ALL getting changed to text-dang.

```
$('.balance').each(function (i) {
    var content = $(this).text().replace('$', '');
    var balance = parseInt(content, 10);

    if (balance <= 0)
    {
        $('.balance').removeClass("text-succ").addClass("text-dang");
    }
    else {
        $('.balance').removeClass("text-dang").addClass("text-succ");
    }
});
```

I have also tried it without the wrapping function - `$('.balance').each(function (i) {` - but then only the FIRST element with class .balance was selected.

Here is my HTML. (Note that I am using Razor, and iterating through multiple accounts which will all contain this h2. The balances were coming in just fine until I used the wrapping function.)

```
<h2>
 <strong>@account.Name</strong> 
 <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
 Balance: <span class="balance text-succ">$ @account.Balance</span>
</h2>
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript and StackOverflow so please let me know if you need more information. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$(this).removeClass("text-succ").addClass("text-dang");`

Comment: You are applying `removeClass` and `addClass` to `.balance`. You want to do that on the current item. @PranavCBalan comment is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply and remove class to the referred element, in this case **$(this)** instead of **$('.balance')**.

Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/vtqtykay/2/)**

```
$('.balance').each(function(){
    var balance = parseInt($(this).text().replace('$',''), 10);
    $(this).removeClass("text-dang").addClass("text-succ");
    if (balance <= 0)
        $(this).removeClass("text-succ").addClass("text-dang");   
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I both love and hate how simple most solutions are in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're updating all elements on each iteration.  You need to use `this` to select the current element.

```js
$('.balance').each(function(i) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var content = $this.text().replace('$', '');
  var balance = parseInt(content, 10);

  if (balance <= 0) {
    $this.removeClass("text-succ").addClass("text-dang");
  } else {
    $this.removeClass("text-dang").addClass("text-succ");
  }
});
```

```css
.text-succ {
  color: green;
}
.text-dang {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><strong>Account1</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Balance: <span class="balance text-succ">-4</span></h2>
<h2><strong>Account2</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Balance: <span class="balance">-2</span></h2>
<h2><strong>Account3</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Balance: <span class="balance">0</span></h2>
<h2><strong>Account4</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Balance: <span class="balance">2</span></h2>
<h2><strong>Account5</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Balance: <span class="balance">4</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

remember you are looping through all elements... when $('.balance').each loops call the anonymous function and uses $(this) to refer to the $(".balance") element that is object of the iteration...

```
$('.balance').each(function (i) {
var content = $(this).text().replace('$', '');
var balance = parseInt(content, 10);

if (balance <= 0)
{
    $(this).removeClass("text-succ").addClass("text-dang");
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass("text-dang").addClass("text-succ");
}});
```

There is a [toogleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) that could take two parameters, one the string for the class and the second one a logic test... so you could do something like:

```
$('.balance').each(function (i) {
var content = $(this).text().replace('$', '');
var balance = parseInt(content, 10);

//to be on the safe side:
$(this).removeClass();// or $(this).removeClass("text-dang text-succ");
$(this).toggleClass("text-dang", balance <= 0);    
$(this).toggleClass("text-succ", balance > 0);
});
```

Well is just an idea...